# Chromebook displaying symbols instead of letters on some webpages

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-os, chromebook

I have been trying to figure out how to get rid of these symbols that show up on my Chromebook (on only some webpages):

[image: symbols]

When I copy them and paste them, they show the correct words.

How can I get rid of these words without resetting all of my settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By resting all of my settings it worked, I had probably clicked and changed some setting.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the language settings under Language and Input Settings.  If you have more than one language, check which is set as "Google Chrome OS is displayed in this language".

Also try clearing "cached images and files" under Settings / More Tools / Clear Browsing Data.

Comment: I only have English (United States) set as my language

Comment: OK.  Try clearing browsing data - under Settings / More Tools.

Comment: I had done that.